# Counting matches in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, tags, match

I need to make a query that will match blogs that have matching `tag_id` in table `tags_blogs`. There is another table that contains the actual tags which I am not concerned about at this stage.

How do I take this table contents:

```
reference_id    tag_id  blog_id
1               1       1   
2               2       1   
3               10      6   
4               11      6   
5               10      7   
6               11      7
7               11      8
```

And return this where (for example) `blog_id = 6`:

```
blog_id  total_matches
7           2
8           1
```

In other words return any blog's ids that have matching tag_id to the parameter provided, as well as a count of how many matches were achieved.

This is the code I have so far (I am way off so far):

```
SELECT blog_id FROM tags_blogs WHERE blog_id = 6
```

Comment: Ok I've just realised that the answers so far don't do what is being asked for here - WHERE blog_id = 6 only returns blog_id that is 6 whereas what I need is a count of tags matches for blogs other than 6. I want to provide an ordered list of similar blogs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, here's more like what you are looking for.  Note that this particular query isn't necessarily optimal

```
select tb.blog_id, count(*) 
  as total_matches 
  from tags_blogs tb
  where tag_id in (select distinct tag_id from tags_blogs where blog_id = 6)
    and blog_id != 6
  group by blog_id
```

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff4b9/1)

You might find that this is a little more efficient in some circumstances, or easier to create:

```
select tb.blog_id, count(*) 
  as total_matches 
  from tags_blogs tb
    join tags_blogs tb1 on tb1.tag_id = tb.tag_id and tb1.blog_id != tb.blog_id
    where tb1.blog_id = 6
  group by tb.blog_id;
```

Comment: This only returns the count of tags from blog_id = 6. Trying to produce a list of similar blogs here with a count so I can order them according to how well they match

Comment: Why do you `distinct` in the first query?

Comment: @zerkms - Mostly habit.  For this answer, it doesn't matter too much, but if it was an in statement,blog_id in (6,7), then the distinct would reduce the returned values, possibly speeding up the outer query.

Comment: @Brian Hoover: "hen the distinct would reduce the returned values, possibly speeding up the outer query" --- it would never happen. mysql optimizes that query into the plan similar to the `JOIN` one. So `DISTINCT` in such a query would only make it slower. And from my experience - in 99% cases `DISTINCT` points to the issue with database design or wrong query.

Answer (score 2):

You need a subquery to select all of 6 (or whatever blog id) tags and if a blog has a tag id IN that subquery it gets selected, then groups same blog_ids together and counts them.

```
SELECT 
     a.blog_id,
     count(*) as total_matches
FROM 
     tags_blogs as a
WHERE 
     a.tag_id IN
     ( SELECT tag_id FROM tags_blogs WHERE b.blog_id=6 ) AND
     a.blog_id!=6 
GROUP BY a.blog_id
```

will return results like

```
blog_id   total_matches
7         2
8         2
```

Comment: @AmyNevill, group by tag_id if you are wanting the count for number of tags each blog has

Comment: @AmyNeville, updated answer to new query that should fit your needs.

Comment: um this seems to produce something similar but not what I was looking for. Basically I want to get a list of blog_ids that had matching tags to the blog_id provided in the parameter. There's an example of what ideally the results should look like in the question. Thanks again for helping out :)

Comment: Ok let me put it in simpler way of explaining. If I input parameter blog_id = 6 I should get the blog_ids 7 and 8 and a count of how many tags matched for those blogs